# how to fetch mapped columns in prisma2

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I am new to prisma2 and I have created the below model schema with @map annotation

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String  @map("user_name")
}
```

Now when i see in my db I am having two columns in User table **id and user_name** but when i am fetching the data from user table like below:

**`const users = prisma.users.findMany()`**

So i am getting data like

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name: null
    }
]
```

Because the schema points to name where as name is mapped to user_name, please help me how can i fetch the db column user_name in the result alias as name

output should be like below:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        user_name: "name value"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`@map` Maps a field name or enum value from the Prisma schema to a column or document field with a different name in the database.
So in your database the name of the column will be `user_name` but in the generated client the name of the field will be `name`.

@map does change the field names in the generated client.

If you want to use user_name in the response you will need to define it as `user_name` in your schema file.

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_name String
}
```

[@map reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map)